# Collect set by group?

Tags: python, hive

I am working with Hive data pulled into a Python Jupyter notebook using a Hive wrapper written in Python. I have terabytes of data like the following:

```
Table 1: time=t1
uid   colA
1     A
1     B
1     C
2     A
2     B
3     C
3     D
```

I would like to create a new dataframe (PySpark/Pandas) from the above data that looks like:

```
Table 2: time=t1
uid   colA
1     [A, B, C]
2     [A, B]
3     [C, D]
```

where `colA` would be a list of strings. How would I do this? I've read about collect_set(), but am not familiar with its use or approriateness.

After creating `Table 2`, suppose I had another table for `time=t2`:

```
Table 3: time=t2
uid   colA
1     [A, B]
2     [B]
3     [C, D, E]
```

Now, I'd like to calculate the set difference between `table 2` and `table 3`. It should return 3, since this is the number of additions/deletions needed to get from Table 3 to Table 2.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Here is summarized solution for problem. Hope this will work for you using pyspark.

**Global Imports:-**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
```

**Table 2 Creation Code:-**

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([
        [1,'A'], [1,'B'], [1,'C'], [2,'A'], [2,'B'], [3, 'C'], [3,'D']
       ]).toDF(['uid', 'colA']).groupBy("uid").agg(F.collect_set("colA").alias("colA"))

df1.show()
+---+---------+
|uid|     colA|
+---+---------+
|  1|[A, B, C]|
|  2|   [A, B]|
|  3|   [C, D]|
+---+---------+
```

**Table 3 Creation Code:-**

```
df2 = sc.parallelize([[1, ['A', 'B']],[2, ['B']],[3, ['C', 'D', 'E']]]).toDF(['uid', 'colA'])
def diffUdfFunc(x,y):
    return list(set(y).difference(set(x)))

diffUdf = F.udf(diffUdfFunc,T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
finaldf = df1.withColumnRenamed("colA", "colA1").join(df2, "uid").withColumnRenamed("colA", "colA2").withColumn("diffCol", diffUdf(F.col("colA1"), F.col("colA2")))
finaldf.select("uid", F.col("diffCol").alias("colA")).where(F.size("colA") > 0).show()
+---+----+
|uid|colA|
+---+----+
|  3| [E]|
+---+----+
```