# Pyspark or SQL return strings from another table whose row ID correspond to an array in another table

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have one table in the format

```
string_1 | id_array
"a"      | [2,3,4]
"c"      | [2,4,5]
```

and another table:

```
id | string_2
1  | s1
2  | s2
3  | s3
4  | s4
5  | s5
```

The `id_array` values correspond to the id values in the second table.

Basically I want to replace the `id_array` values in the first table with the corresponding string values in the second table to have something like this:

```
string_1 | id_array_string
"a"      | [s2,s3,s4]
"c"      | [s2,s4,s5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you tried but here is basic code snippet form my side.
I am taking df1 as dataframe for table 1 and so on df2.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1.select("string_1",F.explode("id_array").alias("id_array")).join(df2, df1.id_array = df2.id).groupBy("string_1").agg(F.collect_set("string_2").alias("id_array_string")).show()
```

I didn't tested but this will work for you. For more ref check similar answer [Collect set by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910601/collect-set-by-group/)

Comment: if this worked without any error and didn't get any data then we need to change datatype for id_array